# Looping performance between, vanilla array, stream, static method

Tags: java, java-8

I hava a collection of Foo object with a method getBar(). I want to make a set of Bar object if instance != Bar.n.

**Updated:** seem  Holger's comments

```
public enum Bar {
    n,
    t;
}
public enum BarSet {
    n( ),
    N( Bar.n ),
    T( Bar.t ),
    TN( Bar.t, Bar.n );

    private final Set<Bar> set;

    public static BarSet getByContent( final Set<Bar> set ){
        final EnumSet<BarSet> tvset = EnumSet.allOf( BarSet.class );
        return tvset.stream()
                    .filter( (i) -> i.set.equals( set ) )
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse( n );
    }

    BarSet( final Set<Bar> set ){
        this.set = set;
    }

    BarSet( final Bar... set ){
        this.set = Arrays.asList(set)
                         .stream()
                         .collect( Collectors.toCollection( () -> EnumSet.noneOf(Bar.class) ));
    }

    BarSet( final Bar bar ){
        this.set = EnumSet.of( bar );
    }

    BarSet( ){
        this.set = EnumSet.noneOf( Bar.class );
    }
    public Set<Bar> getSet(){
        return set;
    }

}
public class Foo {
    private final String name;
    private final Bar    bar;

    public Foo( final String name, final Bar bar){
        this.name   = name;
        this.bar    = bar;
    }

    public Bar getBar(){
        return bar;
    }
}
```

I use jmh framework to bench some implementation

```
public class Bench {
    final static Foo a = new Foo ( "a", Bar.n );
    final static Foo b = new Foo ( "b", Bar.t );
    final static Foo c = new Foo ( "c", Bar.t );
    final static Foo d = new Foo ( "d", Bar.t );
    final static Foo e = new Foo ( "e", Bar.t );
    final static Foo f = new Foo ( "f", Bar.t );
    final static Foo g = new Foo ( "g", Bar.t );
    final static Foo h = new Foo ( "h", Bar.n );
    final static Foo i = new Foo ( "i", Bar.t );
    final static Foo j = new Foo ( "j", Bar.t );
    final static Foo k = new Foo ( "k", Bar.t );
    final static Foo l = new Foo ( "l", Bar.t );
    final static Foo m = new Foo ( "m", Bar.t );
    final static Foo n = new Foo ( "n", Bar.n );
    final static Foo o = new Foo ( "o", Bar.t );
    final static Foo p = new Foo ( "p", Bar.t );
    final static Foo q = new Foo ( "q", Bar.n );
    final static Foo r = new Foo ( "r", Bar.t );
    final static Foo s = new Foo ( "s", Bar.t );
    final static Foo t = new Foo ( "t", Bar.t );
    final static Foo u = new Foo ( "u", Bar.n );
    final static Foo v = new Foo ( "v", Bar.t );
    final static Foo w = new Foo ( "w", Bar.t );
    final static Foo x = new Foo ( "x", Bar.t );
    final static Foo y = new Foo ( "y", Bar.t );
    final static Foo z = new Foo ( "z", Bar.t );

    final static Set<Foo> FOOS = Stream.of( a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s,t, u, v, w, x, y, z )
                                       .collect( Collectors.toSet() );

    public static BarSet union1( final Foo... foos ) {
        final Set<Bar> set = Arrays.stream( foos )
                                     .map( Foo::getBar )
                                     .filter( item -> item != Bar.n )
                                     .collect( Collectors.toCollection( () -> EnumSet.noneOf( Bar.class ) ) );
        return BarSet.getByContent( set );
    }

    public static BarSet union2(  final Foo... foos ){

        final Set<Bar> set = EnumSet.noneOf(Bar.class);
        for( final Foo foo : foos)
            set.add( foo.getBar() );
        set.remove(Bar.n);
        return BarSet.getByContent( set );
    }

    public static BarSet union3( final Foo... foos ) {
        final Set<Bar> set = Arrays.stream( foos )
                                     .map( Foo::getBar )
                                     .collect( Collectors.toCollection( () -> EnumSet.noneOf( Bar.class ) ) );
        set.remove(Bar.n);
        return BarSet.getByContent( set );
    }

    public static BarSet union4( final Foo... foos ) {
        final Set<Bar> set = EnumSet.noneOf( Bar.class );
        set.addAll( Arrays.stream( foos )
                          .map( Foo::getBar )
                          .collect( Collectors.toList() ) );
        set.remove(Bar.n);
        return BarSet.getByContent( set );
    }

    public static BarSet union5( final Foo... foos ) {
        final Set<Bar> set = EnumSet.noneOf( Bar.class );
        set.addAll( Arrays.stream( foos )
                          .map( Foo::getBar )
                          .filter( i -> i != Bar.n )
                          .collect( Collectors.toSet() ) );
        return BarSet.getByContent( set );
    }

    public static BarSet union6( final Foo... foos ) {
        final Set<Bar> set = EnumSet.noneOf( Bar.class );
        set.addAll( Arrays.stream( foos )
                          .map( Foo::getBar )
                          .filter( i -> i != Bar.n )
                          .collect( Collectors.toList() ) );
        return BarSet.getByContent( set );
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void makeArrayBeforeUnion1( final Blackhole blackhole ){
        blackhole.consume( union1( FOOS.toArray( new Foo[ FOOS.size()] ) ) );
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void makeArrayBeforeUnion2( final Blackhole blackhole ){
        blackhole.consume( union2( FOOS.toArray( new Foo[ FOOS.size()] ) ) );
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void makeArrayBeforeUnion3( final Blackhole blackhole ){
        blackhole.consume( union3( FOOS.toArray( new Foo[ FOOS.size()] ) ) );
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void makeArrayBeforeUnion4( final Blackhole blackhole ){
        blackhole.consume( union4( FOOS.toArray( new Foo[ FOOS.size()] ) ) );
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void makeArrayBeforeUnion5( final Blackhole blackhole ){
        blackhole.consume( union5( FOOS.toArray( new Foo[ FOOS.size()] ) ) );
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void makeArrayBeforeUnion6( final Blackhole blackhole ){
        blackhole.consume( union6( FOOS.toArray( new Foo[ FOOS.size()] ) ) );
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void mapUnion( final Blackhole blackhole ) {
        final Set set = FOOS.stream()
                          .map( Foo::getBar )
                          .filter( item -> item != Bar.n )
                          .collect( Collectors.toCollection( () -> EnumSet.noneOf( Bar.class ) ) );
        final BarSet bSet = BarSet.getByContent( set );
        blackhole.consume( bSet );
    }
}
```

Result with 4 warmup and 30 iterations (java 1.8.0_92-b14)

```
Benchmark                     Mode  Cnt        Score        Error  Units
Bench.makeArrayBeforeUnion1  thrpt  120  2832840,288 ±  15446,797  ops/s
Bench.makeArrayBeforeUnion2  thrpt  120  4586215,760 ±  73296,669  ops/s
Bench.makeArrayBeforeUnion3  thrpt  120  3548963,643 ±  18378,086  ops/s
Bench.makeArrayBeforeUnion4  thrpt  120  1883822,039 ±  14916,883  ops/s
Bench.makeArrayBeforeUnion5  thrpt  120  1702718,240 ±  73004,058  ops/s
Bench.makeArrayBeforeUnion6  thrpt  120  1805374,681 ±   8351,091  ops/s
Bench.mapUnion               thrpt  120  2415874,214 ± 139763,688  ops/s
```

Why makeArrayBeforeUnion2 is faster than mapUnion ?

`makeArrayBeforeUnion2` Convert a `Set` to an array by asking to the JVM some memory and fill the new array before start to processing. While `mapUnion` process directly through a stream.

`makeArrayBeforeUnion1` Convert a `Set` to an array and inside the function do the same process than `mapUnion`. And it is a bit more faster than `mapUnion`

Comment: Just a side question: why are you using `Arrays.asList( foos ).stream()` instead of just `Arrays.stream(foos)`?

Comment: Did you test with more warmup and more iterations? And with a more recent JVM?

Comment: Thanks Holger, I took the jdk1.8.0_92 and used Arrays.stream(foos).  And Increase the number of items into Set<Foo> e upto 26 Bar. results: http://paste.fedoraproject.org/371093/14642689/

Comment: Update your question instead of referring to external sites.